# Spark Excel Write options

Tags: excel, scala, apache-spark

How to make column name bold while write scala data-frame to excel? I have tried a below code but not working:

```
DF.write
     .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
     .option("dataAddress", "'Mysheet1'!B3")
     .option("useHeader", "true")
     .mode("append") // Optional, default: overwrite.
     .save("path")
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._

val df: DataFrame = ???
df.write
  .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
  .option("dataAddress", "'My Sheet'!B3:C35")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("bold", "true")
  .option("dateFormat", "yy-mmm-d") // Optional, default: yy-m-d h:mm
  .option("timestampFormat", "mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss") // Optional, default: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000
  .mode("append") // Optional, default: overwrite.
  .save("Worktime2.xlsx")
```

https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel

Comment: Well, 'it's not working' is not very conducive to debugging the actual error.  It must throw an error message, or it would complete successfully.  Look at the exact and error and try to figure it out.  Google the error message.  That should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Well it's not throwing any error but also it is not making column name bold

Comment: I believe the code that I gave you is correct, or very close to it.  Something could have changed very recently.  The team that invented Spark changes things ALL THE TIME, so make sure all your libraries are up to date.  I don't have access to Spark right now, so I can't test it.  I guess you need to ask a new question at this point.

Comment: @ASH Could you please help me to make some column as read-only while writing to excel format using Crealytics spark-excel library

Comment: Read-only in Excel? I think you need VBA for that, or at least something in Excel, itself. There is no way Spark can control that! https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4078-excel-make-cell-read-only.html

Comment: @ASH, Actually I'm working on a task, where I'm reading a data from SQL and post some data manipulations, I've to store it in a excel file format with few column as a read only nature? Do you have any better approach regarding the same?

Comment: Well, Databricks won't handle it. That's impossible. Use VBA after your data is written and saved to Excel. For instance, you can create a very simple Excel file, with VBA embedded inside, to open another Excel file, do the work, save all changes, and close it.

Comment: Or, just use VBA to grab data from SQL Server. You don't need Databricks to grab data, unless the data is HUGE.